# understanding what this line of code does

Tags: c++

So I'm supposed to write a function that deletes a duplicate and was having a hard time understanding a certain line.

```
void repeat(char arr[], int times[],int &arraySize)
{
  {
    for(int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
      for(int j =i+1; j<arraySize; j++)
      {
        if(arr[i]==arr[j])
        {
          for(int c = j; c < arraySize-1; c++){
            arr[c] = arr[c+1];
          }
          arraySize--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



***for(int c = j; c < arraySize-1; c++){
                arr[c] = arr[c+1];***
```

Are these lines looping through all the way to the last element of the array? Also a bit confused about arr[c] = arr[c+1]; why do we need that?

Comment: What don't you understand about it?  Try putting the code into words, it should make sense.

Comment: Aarg... this is just C code,  except for the reference to arraySize, that would otherwise be a pointer.  Our the return value. C++ has std::string for this.

Comment: If you are trying to write "a function that deletes a duplicate", I would advise you to give it a name completely different from `remove()`.  I would also advise you to *not* pass it an irrelevant `times[]` array.  Also, the function that you have posted does not delete a duplicate; instead, it searches for duplicates, and it removes every single one of them.  The code that deletes a duplicate is just the innermost four lines or so.  (The `for` loop and the `arraySize--;` statement.)

Answer (score 0):

To delete an element in an array (whether duplicate or not -- that's irrelevant) you have to move all of the remaining elements one position down, to cover the element being deleted.  And when we say 'move' we actually mean 'copy'.

So, the loop that you see replaces each element from `j` to `arraySize - 1` with the element immediately following it.  The last element does not need to be replaced, and in fact is not replaced, because the statement `arraySize--;` ensures that it will never be considered again.

(Also, if you think about it, if it was to be replaced, what would it be replaced with?  There is no element at position `[arraySize]`!  C++ arrays are indexed from zero, so the valid elements are from `[0]` to `[arraySize - 1]`.)

Comment: "ensures that it will never be considered again" ? "ensures" is maybe a bit too strong, considering that `std::vector` exists that actually can ensure a removed element cannot be accessed anymore